# Absolutely strange behavior in creating of instance

Tags: c#

I will show you two screenshots and I am interested why it does ... what it does.

In the first screenshot you can see that I am able to create an instance of `List<SelectListItem>` named `s`, but one line after that, an exception is thrown and I am not able to create instance of same list named `selectListItem`.

On the second screenshot you can see that if I declare list above condition, I am able to create an instance of `List<SelectListItem>` named `selectListItem` on the same position.

Please, what it caused?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Main menu, Build: Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution.  And make sure everything is deployed correctly.

Comment: I did try - it did not help

Comment: Step through this line by line, @lawliet is almost certainly correct in that the problem is occurring in the closure when it tries to references the Id or Name properties of the object.

Comment: Hmm, I think, we have misunderstand in question. Becouse in the second screenshot it is correct - it stopped on breakpoint. However I want to know why I cannot create instance named selectListItem, if I haven't got declaration above condition. It can't do Id or something under broken line.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that something weird is happening when you reference selectListItem later in a closure.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var selectListItem = ServiceProductModel
    .GetAll()
    .Select(spm => new SelectListItem {
        Value = spm.Id.ToString(),
        Text = string.Format(@"{0}", spm.Name)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, though I would add one thing to this: spm might be null, or spm.Id might be null.

Comment: it fall when creating instance. Line about what you are talking is never run.

Comment: With this code you don't need to create an instance, it is created by `.ToList()`

Comment: yeah, but I need to know why I cannot create instance. (Second screenshot is stopped on breakpoint - first one is incorrect)

Comment: @Ademar I'd say it's probably due to a null reference.

Comment: @asawyer Sorry, I don't get it. What problem with null reference can be in line `List<SelectListItem> selectListItem = new List<SelectListItem>()` (and if I change instance name, it works)?

Comment: Like I said, problem is most likely that your variable `selectListItem` is later referenced in a lambda. So variable definition point can actually go haywire and debugger wouldn't be able to point you an exact location in code where this exception occurs.